# holoview.extension('bokeh') - cannot import extension

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, holoviews

I wanted to test HoloViews, but I encounter several errors.
I installed it twice (different sets as suggested [here](http://holoviews.org/install.html)). I used `!pip install holoviews` and `!pip install 'holoviews[recommended]'`.

While installing I got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: holoviews in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Requirement already satisfied: param>=1.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from holoviews)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from holoviews)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarningenter
```

So, I can import HoloViews (it's in the list of installed packages as version 1.6.2), but then holoviews.extension('bokeh') doesn't work. So I can't use it.

I'm using

- Python 2.7.6
- Jupyter Notebook 5.1.0
- Bokeh 0.12.9
- Numpy 1.13.1
- Pandas 0.20.3

I would appreciate any hint on what I'm doing wrong or what I can do to solve this. I'm not really familiar with installing packages. If you need more information, let me know. I spend a few hours searching/googling for answers with no results.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the inclusion of `pip install bokeh`, I am finding that `pip install holoviews[recommended]` works correctly in a clean Python 2 environment. This installs the latest HoloViews release which is 1.9.2.

It looks like there might be an older holoviews installation on your system, so I would recommend trying it again in a clean Python 2 environment. Alternatively, try pinning the version by running `pip install holoviews[recommended]==1.9.2`. Note you will need bokeh version 0.12.13 as well, so you make sure to run `pip install bokeh==0.12.13` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I had to pass on the update of the libraries to other employees because I apparently do not have writing permission on some folders. I made explicit reference to the versions from your tip. When I know what worked, I'll let you know.
Thanks again!